# ground geom_text to x axis (e.g. y =0)

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, geom-text

I have a graph made in ggplot that looks like this:

[image: bubblegum]

I wish to have the numeric labels at each of the bars to be grounded/glued to the x axis where y <= 0.

This is the code to generate the graph as such:

```
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=row, y=numofpics, fill = crop, group = 1), stat='identity') +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x = df$row, y=df$numofparcels*50, group = 2), alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_line(data=df, aes(x = df$row, y=df$numofparcels*50, group = 2), alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_text(aes(x=row, y=numofpics, label=bbch)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=300, linetype="dashed", color = "red", size=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis= sec_axis(~./50, name="Number of Parcels")) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = c(),breaks = unique(df$crop), labels = as.character(unique(df$crop)))+
  labs(x=c(), y="Number of Pictures")
```

I've tried `vjust` and experimenting with `position_nudge` for the `geom_text` element, but every solution I can find changes the position of each element of the `geom_text` respective to its current position. As such everything I try results in situation like this one:

[image: bubblegum2]

How can I make ggplot ground the text to the bottom of the x axis where y <= 0, possibly with the possibility to also introduce a `angle = 45`?

Link to dataframe = https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b-5AfBECap3TZjlpLhl1m3v74Lept2em/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What about `geom_text(aes(x=row, y=-100, label=bbch))` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments, just set the y-coordinate of the text to 0 or below, and specify the angle : `geom_text(aes(x=row, y=-100, label=bbch), angle=45)`

[image]

Comment: all of the answers were good, but the simplicity of this one appealed the most to me. thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

I'm behind a proxy server that blocks connections to google drive so I can't access your data. I'm not able to test this, but I would introduce a new label field in my dataset that sets y to be 0 if y<0:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(labelField = if_else(numofpics<0, 0, numofpics)
```

I would then use this label field in my geom_text call:

```
geom_text(aes(x=row, y=labelField, label=bbch), angle = 45)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define the y-value in geom_text (e.g. -50)

```
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=row, y=numofpics, fill = crop, group = 1), stat='identity') +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x = df$row, y=df$numofparcels*50, group = 2), alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_line(data=df, aes(x = df$row, y=df$numofparcels*50, group = 2), alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_text(aes(x=row, y=-50, label=bbch)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=300, linetype="dashed", color = "red", size=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis= sec_axis(~./50, name="Number of Parcels")) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = c(),breaks = unique(df$crop), labels =
```

as.character(unique(df$crop)))+
      labs(x=c(), y="Number of Pictures")